# Adding a new language to Xcode4 localization?

Tags: xcode4, localization

The app in question is already localized into a few languages, but I'm adding a new one. When I choose to add the new language to Localizable.strings, it places it in the root of the project directory. I'd ideally like it inside Resources, then a directory for the language, but I don't see an option to change the location when creating the localization or afterward. If I move it in Finder, there's no option to tell Xcode where I moved it to, it just colors the filename red and can't find it.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After moving a file in Finder go back to Xcode, select the file, then open the File Inspector (View - Utilities - Show File Inspector). Click the little arrow near the file name and navigate to the new location.

Sorry can't help you with why Xcode places the files under root directory and not .lproj. My Xcode here does it